# After something is added to a string, how do I print the modification as well as the rest of the string?

Tags: python

So the title might not make sense. But here is the code:

```
def play_game(ml_string, blanks, selectedLevel):


replaced = []
ml_string = ml_string.split()
currentQuestion = 0


for blank in ml_string:
    replacement = blank_in_quiz(blank, blanks,)
    if replacement != None:
        user_input = raw_input("Type in the answer for blank " + replacement + " ")
        while user_input != allanswers[selectedLevel][currentQuestion]:
            print "Incorrect!"
            user_input = raw_input("Type in the answer for blank " + replacement + " ")
        else:
            blank = blank.replace(replacement, user_input)
            replaced.append(blank)
            print "\nCorrect!\n"
            print " ".join(replaced + [currentQuestion,ml_string])
            currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1
    else:
        replaced.append(blank)
replaced = " ".join(replaced)
print replaced
```

Essentially what this does is take this string, which is ml_string:

```
"The movie __1__ is a war movie directed by __2__ Nolan about the __3__ and French armies stranded on the __4__ of Dunkirk while the __5__ army closed in on them."
```

And once the user adds the correct answer to the blank, I am trying to print out the answer filled in the blank, as well as the rest of the quiz with the blanks they haven't answered yet.

I am a beginner at python, but I've always struggled with lists and index values. If you would like to view the entirety: https://repl.it/KTJh/16

Line 55 is what I'm having trouble with. Thanks for any kind of advice.

Comment: A regex would probably work, but you're kind of doing this is an overly complicated fashion. I'd probably store the complete strings separately, then add in the "underscore fillers" only when you want it to print out. I can see that being much easier than trying to replace bits of an existing string.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that's interesting. I'll try to implement that

Comment: That way, once the user gets an answer right, you can just replace the filler with the right answer. I'd try to elaborate, but I just got off of a night shift and feel brain dead. Good luck.

Comment: If Python has an "interleave" function for lists, you could just `interleave` the complete strings and the fillers/answers, then `join` the separate strings using an empty string. Then just replace the entire in the filler/answer list as the user answers them right.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. You helped me out on my last problem too.

Comment: Np. Unfortunately Python doesn't seem to have an `interleave` function built in, but a quick google search shows many implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to create your string with *placeholders* (replacement_field) that get filled in with some predefined variables, as the users answers you just change the variables.  The format specification allows named placeholders

```
s = "The movie {ans1} is a war movie directed by {ans2} Nolan about the {ans3} and French armies stranded on the {ans4} of Dunkirk while the {ans5} army closed in on them."
```

Which makes it convenient to fill in the placeholders with a dictionary

```
d = {'ans1' : '__1__', 'ans2' : '__2__',
     'ans3' : '__3__', 'ans4' : '__4__',
     'ans5' : '__5__'}
```

You use it like this:

```
>>> s.format(**d)
'The movie __1__ is a war movie directed by __2__ Nolan about the __3__ and French armies stranded on the __4__ of Dunkirk while the __5__ army closed in on them.'
```

Change the answers like this

```
>>> d['ans1'] = 'Ziegfield Follies'
>>> s.format(**d)
'The movie Ziegfield Follies is a war movie directed by __2__ Nolan about the __3__ and French armies stranded on the __4__ of Dunkirk while the __5__ army closed in on them.'
>>>
```

Comment: Oh, that's a neat idea too. Probably more Pythonic than my suggestion.

Comment: That's really interesting. I haven't learned or even seen any examples of dictionaries in python yet. It looks more efficient than basics lists, like I'm trying to do. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Carcigenicate I read your comment while writing this and the ideas are basically the same I almost gave you a mention.

Comment: @louielouielouie - you should take the time to work through [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) , you will have a better idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problems.

Comment: @wwii My Python is rusty, but this looks like string replacement, whereas I was suggesting interleaving the fillers with the strings. Should have identical results though.

Comment: @louielouielouie And I agree with wwii. When learning to program in a new language, one of the best things you can do starting out is to learn what tools you have at your disposal. It's hard to know how to solve a problem when you aren't sure what options you have available to you. Python has a huge page outlining all their built-in functions. It's definitely worth studying.

Comment: @wwii thanks for that tutorial link, that will help.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah, it's been really frustrating trying to get through this project. I feel like there are a ton of tools I could use that would make my life way easier, but they were never taught to us. I get they want us to think on our own. But at least they should've introduced all of the tools we could use.

Comment: @louielouielouie Python has some of the best documentation out there. Any time spent reading over any of it is time well spent. Definitely check out that link he posted. And good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the latest Python to learn (3.6), your could use f-strings.  The items in curly braces can be most Python expressions.  In this case, they index a word list:

```
import textwrap

def paragraph(words):
    s = f'The movie {words[0]} is a war movie directed by {words[1]} Nolan about the {words[2]} and French armies stranded on the {words[3]} of Dunkirk while the {words[4]} army closed in on them.'
    print()
    print(textwrap.fill(s))

words = '__1__ __2__ __3__ __4__ __5__'.split()
paragraph(words)
words[0] = 'Dunkirk'
paragraph(words)
```

Output:

```
The movie __1__ is a war movie directed by __2__ Nolan about the __3__
and French armies stranded on the __4__ of Dunkirk while the __5__
army closed in on them.

The movie Dunkirk is a war movie directed by __2__ Nolan about the
__3__ and French armies stranded on the __4__ of Dunkirk while the
__5__ army closed in on them.
```